# Why Spring Boot Actuator adds JMX MBean named 'Tomcat-1'?

Tags: spring-boot

Without Spring Boot Actuator, I have MBean named 'Tomcat'.

But with Spring Boot Actuator,

I have another MBean named 'Tomcat-1' which looks like MBean named 'Tomcat'.

Did I mis-configure something? or a bug of the Actuator? or an intended feature of it?

Answer (score 0):

'Tomcat-1' is for the Tomcat instance for management.

I set 'management.port' property to service it on another port.

I didn't watch my log messages carefully.

There was the answer.